# Crear carpetas anidadas desde cmd

Tags: bucle-for, cmd

Estoy tratando de crear un programa en cmd que me permita crear carpetas anidadas; es decir, qué el usuario digite un número y cree ese numero de carpetas, pero una dentro de otra.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento, pero no funciona.

```
 cls
        title Bienvendio sesion de Ricardo
        echo Bienvendio sesion de Ricardo Perez
        echo.Digigte 543 para salir
        set /p ciclo="¿A Que nivel desea ingresar?"
      set /p  x=0
        if %x%<=%ciclo% goto crear
        
:crear

mkdir%x%
cd%x%
set /a x=x+1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Breve Explicación

Para poder generar carpetas anidadas debemos obtener la cantidad de carpetas, una vez obtenidas iniciaremos un bucle del rango de la cantidad.

En el bucle crearemos la carpeta y nos posicionaremos en la ruta de esa carpeta para que cuando el bucle vuelva a ser activado la carpeta se cree dentro de esta.

## Código

```
@echo off

REM Obtenemos la cantidad de carpetas
set/p cantidad=Cantidad de carpetas:

REM Iniciamos el bucle
for /l %%a in (1, 1, %cantidad%) do (
    mkdir Carpeta
    cd Carpeta
)
```